# AND OR logic in Dax PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to Power BI and want to create a simple employee count as of 1/1/2016 (for example) based on hire and term dates. Basically, count empid if the employee's hire date is less than or equal to 1/1/2016 AND (Termdate is null OR Termdate is greater than 1/1/2016).  I foolishly thought Dax would accept such AND/OR syntax but it clearly is not working:

```
HeadcountJan-1-2016 = CALCULATE(SUM('Employees'[DistCountEmpID]),
  ('Employees’ [Hire Date] <= date(2016,01,01) AND
    (ISBLANK('Employees'[Termination Date] OR
      'Employees'[Termination Date] > date(2016,01,01)
    ))
```

Any ideas on the correct syntax for this?

Comment: AND/OR works differently on DAX. It's first the AND/OR, followed by the 2 logical values you want to test. So I would say it should be like this: `CALCULATE((COUNT('Employees'[DistCountEmpID])),(OR(AND('Employees’ [Hire Date] <= date(2016,01,01),ISBLANK('Employees'[Termination Date])),'Employees'[Termination Date] > date(2016,01,01))))`. Let me know if it works, It should, but I couldn't test it myself yet

Answer (score 1):

DenStudent, Thanks, but for some reason, when I used your syntax, I got a multiple column error, however, it appears that this structure works:

CALCULATE(SUM('Employees'[DistCountEmpID]), 'Employees'[Hire Date] <= date(2016,01,01), OR(ISBLANK('Employees'[Termination Date]), 'Employees'[Termination Date] > date(2016,01,01)))